# Multiple dropdowns on mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I create multiple dropdowns in my view with values coming from my database? I can get one dropdown, but how do I add another one?

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List { get; set; }

     }


public ActionResult Page()
    {
        var query = model.MyModel.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {

            Value = c.ModelDescription,
            Text = c.ModelDescription

        });
        var model = new MyModel
        {
            List = query.AsEnumerable()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add more properties to contain your other selectlistitems

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List3 { get; set; }
 }
```

And just run other queries you need to populate them. And then you can just use them in the view.